# How to Observable map nested json objects with different property names

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an json result which has nested objects. I need to cast them to my custom objects which have different property names than the json result.

For the parent object(`Vraag`) I can map them. But for the sub objects(`Antwoord`) I couldn't.

**Json**

```
{
    "question":"Vraag 1",
    "answers":[
        {
            "answer":"Voetbal"
        },
        {
            "answer":"Volleybal"
        }
    ]  
}
```

**My Objects**

```
export class Vraag {
    tekst?: string;
    antwoorden?: Antwoord[];

    constructor(tekst?: string, antwoorden?: Antwoord[]) {
        this.tekst = tekst;
        this.antwoorden = antwoorden;
    }
}

export class Antwoord {
    tekst?: string;

    constructor(tekst?: string) {
        this.tekst = tekst;
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
get(): Observable<Vraag> {
    return this.http.get('the json above')
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .map(({question , answers}) => new Vraag(question , answers)); // answers needs to be fetched inside the object too
}
```

So, how can I map the json like this?:

`new Vraag("Vraag 1" , [new Antwoord("voetbal"),new Antwoord("volleybal")]);`

Comment: `answers.map(answer => new Answer(answer))`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've changed the `new Vraag(question , answers)` as `new Vraag(question , answers.map(({answer}) => new Antwoord(answer)))` so that `answers(Antwoord)` can have multiple different named properties. your comment helped me to get on the right path.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It gives now the following error: `error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Antwoord[]'.`

Comment: @jonrsharpe my bad, it's working now

Answer (score 2):

You should just map answers array elements to required objects before passing it to `Vraag` constructor. Check the following snippet:

```
get(): Observable<Vraag> {
    return this.http.get('the json above')
                    .map((response: Response) => response.json())
                    .map(({question , answers}) => {
                        answers = answers.map(answer => new Antwoord(answer));
                        new Vraag(question , answers));
                    });
}
```